# Proving $H^n(X,K_X)=\mathbb{C}$ for a compact complex manifold

Tags: complex-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

$X$ is a compact complex manifold of dimension $n$ (Not necessarily Kahler). How would I go about proving the statement above? I know that $H^n(X,K_X)$ is isomorphic to $H^{n,n}(X)$ by Dolbeault's theorem.

Integration gives a well defined map onto $\mathbb{C}$ but I'm not sure how to prove that it's one-one.

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange! This is a nice first question, with your thoughts already spelled out.

Answer (score 2):

The isomorphism $H^n(X,K_X)\simeq\mathbb{C}$ follows from Serre duality, which is valid for every compact complex manifold, Kähler or not.
One version of Serre's fundamental result  is that given a connected complex compact manifold $X$ of dimension $n$, a vector bundle $V$ on $X$ and an integer $p$, the finite-dimensional  vector spaces $$H^p(X,V) \operatorname {and} H^{n-p}(X,K_X\otimes V^*)$$ ( which are finite-dimensional by Cartan-Serre!) are canonically  dual for any integer $p$.
Your isomorphism is obtained by taking $p=n$ and $V=K_X.$

**Bibliography**
[Serre, Un théorème de dualité](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/pdfcache/PPN358147735_0029/PPN358147735_0029___LOG_0005.pdf)

Comment: haha, This is the result that is being proved when the claim is made (Voisin's Complex Geometry 1, page 135). She makes use of this along with the multiplicative structure on these two sheaves. The tensor of these two sheaves gives $K_X$ and she claims that $H^n(X,K_X)$ is $\mathbb{C}$ by integration.

Comment: I think Griffiths-Harris prove this. I'm going through it now.

Comment: OK, I deleted my comment. Are you writing under two pseudonyms?

Comment: yes. previously forgot the password to this account.

Comment: G-H use that $*$ commutes with the $\bar\partial$-Laplacian. Hence there is an isomorphism between harmonic $\mathcal{H}^{0,0}$ and $\mathcal{H}^{n,n}$ forms. This is a little more down to earth than Georges' answer which I would accept if I could access my temporary account. Thanks Georges!

Comment: Don't worry, dear Un idiota: your virtual acceptance is quite satisfactory :-)

Comment: I suggest you might delete the comment in which you say you didn't want to be rude: I know that and I already deleted my comment based on a  misunderstanding (and then I will also delete the present comment).